# Why aren't these throw statements giving me a compiler error?

Tags: java, exception

```
public String runQuery(String q) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException   
 {   
    Graph g = null;
            try {
                g = jdbcTemplate.query(q, new Neo4jGraphResultSetExtractor());
            } catch (DataAccessException e) {

                if (e instanceof UncategorizedSQLException)
                    {
                    //Invalid cypher query
                    throw (UncategorizedSQLException)e;
                    }

                else throw e; 
            }

    json = g.toJson(); //throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException
    return json;
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler require that this method also throws `UncategorizedSQLException`, `DataAccessException`?

Comment: Not if they extend from RuntimeException, which seems to be the case.

Comment: @pedromss Huh - They do. Why shouldn't run time exceptions throw compiler errors? Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Answer (score 0):

Because they are *runtime* exceptions, which are *unchecked* meaning that the compiler does not require explicit catching of them.

[See this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)